# android playing streaming pls files

Tags: android, streaming, media-player

I'm currently building an application and I need your help.

This application can play streaming .pls files from the internet. The problem is I can't figured out what class to play streaming pls file.

I had used the MediaPlayer class, but it got error and stopped working.

This is my piece of code in executing the mediaplayer :

```
try {
                mediaPlayer.setDataSource(site);
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
try {
                    mediaPlayer.prepare();
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    Log.e (getClass().getName(), "Cannot Play Stream..");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    Log.e (getClass().getName(), "Cannot Play Stream..");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                    mediaPlayer.start();
                    break;
```

What should I do ?? need help, THX
(the try-catch statement is automatic in eclipse. I can't compile without the try-catch statement)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you can't play PLS files directly with any of the Android music/sound player classes.

I would use `HttpGet` to download the PLS file and then process it to extract the URL it contains. Once you have the URL of the stream, you can pass that to `MediaPlayer` and it should play it OK.

Comment: I see what you mean, but the my PLS file looks like this when I opened it in notepad

Comment: I didn't see any URL contained in the pls file nor mp3 or any audio file. How can I parse it..?? what is HttpGet ??

Comment: @Jason: The following is the URL rhemafm.serverroom.us:5858 `HTTPGet` is documented here http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/methods/HttpGet.html search for how to use it to download a file. A PLS file is just a text file - you need to read it line by lin until you find one that starts 'File1=' then get what is after the '='. Check to see if it starts 'http://' and if it doesn't then add that at the beginning then simply pass that URL as a String to MediaPlayer.

Comment: well, I see what you mean. Can you give me the sample code plsss?? THX